# Best way to send JSON data.

Tags: php, json, continuous-integration

I have a url

```
http://example.com/data/
```

I want to send json data in that url
i.e.

```
http://example.com/data/{"1":{"id":"some_id","xyz":"1","date":"1397287235418","type":"67878"}}
```

What is the best way to send json data in the url because when I try to send data in this format it gives error

> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

I know there is allowed character configuration in CI but if I allow there will be a security issue.
I have tried urlencode and in server side used urldecode but it's not helping either
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does urlencode also tells disallowed chars?

Comment: Do you want to use the json with javascript?

Comment: why dont you try GET?

Comment: @RoyalBg Yes urlencode also tells disallowed chars.

Comment: @Dinistro json with PHP

Comment: @BlankHead It is my project requirement to send data in POST method . It is a REST API.

Comment: Then try POST. Its not a best way to pass json data details in url as mentioned in the question. Whats the problem with POST then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php `rawurlencode` function escape the invalid character. For example,

```
<?php 
$str = '{"1":{"id":"some_id","xyz":"1","date":"1397287235418","type":"67878"}}';
$str2 = rawurlencode($str);
?>
<a href="/data/<?php echo $str2; ?>">LINK</a>
```

This shows the url

```
http://example.com/data/%7B%221%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22some_id%22%2C%22xyz%22%3A%221%22%2C%22date%22%3A%221397287235418%22%2C%22type%22%3A%2267878%22%7D%7D/
```